# Empty row in Teradata query result

Tags: sql, teradata

I know this might sound weird and but after executing a Teradata query, I am getting the result as such:

```
|  ID  |  Name   |  
+------+---------+      
| 1007 |   Raj   |      
|      |         |           
| 1001 |  Sanjib |    
| 1008 |  Suman  |    
| 1004 |  Mohan  |
```

The 2nd row is just blank. (Sorry, could not edit properly but I hope you get the point) The query is pretty simple.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_names 
FROM table1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

I do not have access to its' DDL statements.
There was also another scenario where this same table was in the output, just without any row elements, just the column names.
I am using SQL WORKBENCH/J. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you can run the Select you can also run a SHOW TABLE. Due to the Outer Join there might be NULLs and those might be displayed as empty strings.

Comment: I did. It does not have any NULLs :(

Comment: What doesn't have NULLs, the result? How do you know? Try add `COALESCE(column, '<NULL>')`

Comment: What does `select count(*) from table1 where id is null` and `select count(*) from table2 where id is null` give you?

Comment: In the display options for SQL WORKBENCH/J, you can specify the value to display for NULL. I don't recall the default, what do you have it set to?

Comment: "column_names"? seriously? voted to close.

Comment: Do you have access to `DBC.ColumnsV`? Check if the table has VARCHAR columns and contains empty strings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks man, it worked. There are plenty of NULLs in the tables